# How to count id and sort by date using charts C# programming

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

What I'm trying to do is to create a chart that will count the total amount of patients then having it sort by date(by day) I have 
Patient ID= id DA=as my day added Date of C= as my date added and DU= as my date updated I'm confused on how I will encode it, and what I'm trying to do is to create a chart that will be showing me the graph of patient count per day

```
 try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText= "select count(PatientID) as id, 
  datename(DA,DateofC)as datename from Patient where 
 datediff(DA,DateofC,getdate()) = 0 group by DateofC";
            OleDbDataReader reader;

            reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                chartControl1.Series["PatientCount"].Points.AddPoint(reader["id"].ToString(),         
               reader.GetInt32(0));
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, what is the difference between DA and DateofC? Also, please edit the code so that we don't have to scroll horizontally to read it.

Comment: DA only gets the day like Monday, Tuesday etc while DateofC gets all the data from date to complete time

Comment: Thanks. You can't feed 'Monday' into a date function. datename will give you the day of the week if you use datename(weekday,mydate), where the weekday bit is a reserved word, not a column name (see e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datename.asp) [apologies if you already knew this]